# UV mapping moves part of the original objects

Tags: mesh, uv

I'm very new to blender and following a tutorial. When i select my objects, parts of every obect appears in a completely different placement on the UV map. I need them to line up with the image.
[image: Everything selected]

[image: Single object selected]

[image: Settings visible]

Comment: Please add an image of Blender's complete window so that we can see what settings you're using and see it at a decent size. You can do this from Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and edit the resulting image into your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "appears in a completely different placement on the UV map", different than what? You can control where exactly the UV will appear over the image in the UV Editor, you need to move the UV faces manually

Comment: @moonboots on the second image you can see i've highlighted a single object and on the UV map it doesn't mirror the selection, the middle of it appears disconnected, it must be something i've done as in the tutorial when he selects his, the selection is mirrored in the UV map